# comparing values with div data jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to filter the data loop with data-id and compare it with the number.
So I check the date-id in the div's and compare the value with my if I match the display message

```js
var ids = $('.div').data('id');
ids.forEach(function(id) {
  if (id == '45') {
    alert('isset 45');
  } else {
    alert('not value 45 in div');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-id="12">12</div>
<div class="div" data-id="33">33</div>
<div class="div" data-id="44">44</div>
<div class="div" data-id="45">45</div>
<div class="div" data-id="54">54</div>
<div class="div" data-id="11">11</div>
```

Unfortunately, the script does not work

Comment: a jQuery accessor only works on the first item of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a each method available in `$('selector')`. Selector will select all the divs and then you can iterated over them one by one and check `data-id`. Also you were extracting the `data-id` before your loop. You have to retrieve it inside the loop.

```js
$('.div').each(function() {
  id = $(this).data('id')
  if (id == '45') {
    alert('isset 45');
  } else {
    alert('not value 45 in div');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-id="12">12</div>
<div class="div" data-id="33">33</div>
<div class="div" data-id="44">44</div>
<div class="div" data-id="45">45</div>
<div class="div" data-id="54">54</div>
<div class="div" data-id="11">11</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because `ids` is a string containing the `data-id` value from the `*first*`.div` element. To fix the immediate problem you need to create an array of the values using an array:

```js
var ids = $('.div').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('id');
}).get();

ids.forEach(function(id) {
  if (id == '45') {
    console.log('isset 45');
  } else {
    console.log('not value 45 in div');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-id="12">12</div>
<div class="div" data-id="33">33</div>
<div class="div" data-id="44">44</div>
<div class="div" data-id="45">45</div>
<div class="div" data-id="54">54</div>
<div class="div" data-id="11">11</div>
```

That being said, a better approach would be find the element(s) directly, then check if anything was found. This method means you don't need to loop:

```js
var $el = $('.div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('id') == 45;
});

if ($el.length) {
  console.log('isset 45');
} else {
  console.log('not value 45 in div');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-id="12">12</div>
<div class="div" data-id="33">33</div>
<div class="div" data-id="44">44</div>
<div class="div" data-id="45">45</div>
<div class="div" data-id="54">54</div>
<div class="div" data-id="11">11</div>
```

Comment: That's true. However it's an odd requirement. Surely you only need to know *once* if the element exists or not.

Answer (score 3):

`data()` will only return the value from fist item of the list.

You don't iteration though, just check

```
var divWith45Exists = $('.div[data-id="45"]').length > 0;
```

**Demo**

```js
var divWith45Exists = $('.div[data-id="45"]').length > 0;
divWith45Exists ? alert( "yes" ) : alert("No");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-id="12">12</div>
<div class="div" data-id="33">33</div>
<div class="div" data-id="44">44</div>
<div class="div" data-id="45">45</div>
<div class="div" data-id="54">54</div>
<div class="div" data-id="11">11</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of possible solution:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // Loop through each div
  $('.div').each(function() {

    // current element
    var el = $(this);

    // value
    var dataId = el.attr('data-id');

    if (dataId == '45') {
      console.log('isset 45');
    } else {
      console.log('not value 45 in div');
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" data-id="12">12</div>
<div class="div" data-id="33">33</div>
<div class="div" data-id="44">44</div>
<div class="div" data-id="45">45</div>
<div class="div" data-id="54">54</div>
<div class="div" data-id="11">11</div>
```